# Общий обработчик не пойманных исключений для всего приложения

Tags: c#, исключения

Хочу сделать общий обработчик не пойманных исключений для всего приложения.
Когда возникает исключение, что бы открылось окно в которое попадет текст ошибки.

О try catch я знаю. Но не всегда он может быть написан.

Comment: как понять - не всегда может быть написан?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) и [Application.ThreadException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx)